# JavaScript XMLHttpRequest.responseType as "arraybuffer" -- how to get current arraybuffer chunk

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to stream a  from the client side to a server side, to later stream the video **back** to another client.

The point is:

How can I get chunks of a video from client-side JavaScript (that can be sent to a server)?

using this code, for example:

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = location.href;
        x.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(x.readyState == 200) {
                console.log("done");
            } else {
                console.log("chunk",x.response); //this is null until readyState is 200 anyway
            }

        }
        x.onprogress = e => {
            console.log("EE",e.target.response); //also null if resposneType is arraybuffer
        };
        x.responseType="arraybuffer";
        x.open("GET","http://localhost:88/videoplayback.mp4",true);
        x.send("");
```

When I try to print the response before its finished loading (to get it by chunks) then its simply null; the arraybuffer only returns as the respnse when its finished loading.

If I take out the responsetype and just leave it as plain text, then indeed some unicode-characters get printed to the screen for each readystatechange even before its finished, only an arraybuffer doesn't.

So: is this the best way to stream a video from the client to server, and if so, how can I actually do it? and if not, what's a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, `arraybuffer` or `blob` responseTypes do not allow access of chunk of data until the download is complete.

Now, there are ways... For instance in newest browsers, you could start a [ReadableStream from the fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams), or from Firefox you could set the `responseType` to `"moz-chunked-buffer"`, but that's not what you need at all here.

What you are describing is exactly what [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/) has been made for. So the best way is to run a STUN/TURN server, and to stream your media through it using the MediaStream API.

Comment: Ooh interesting is WebRTC a built in browser interface thats supported by all?

Comment: WebRTC is a set of standardized APIs, that ultimately all web-browsers following web-standards should support. Now, current browser support is [not that bad](https://caniuse.com/#feat=rtcpeerconnection), but we can't say **all** do support. A few versions away, Edge didn't had support, and IE won't ever have support. So that depends on your audience really, but *most* users should be able to use it.